# Take empty database using wampserver

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

I have a database with tables and these tables have some information.

I want to take an empty copy of this database with the tables

How can I get an empty database without deleting the information in the initial database?

Comment: You dump the full database with the structure (`mysqldump ...`) into a file, then remove the `INSERT` statements in there and finally load the result into a new database.

Comment: Or you read the table creation commands from the existing database and setup the tables one by one. Should be possible to automate this in combination with the `SHOW TABLES` command.

Comment: Oh, and the `mysqldump` command also offers the `--no-data` switch, exactly what you are looking for...

Comment: @arkascha how to do this how to use mysqldump to create that ?!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that question. You mean how to use `mysqldump`? Well, it comes with a man page and a usage if you simply invoke it. Note however that, like most efficient commands, it is a command line utility. Not something that opens a window where you can click buttons or menus. That would be very limited in a typical server environment... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: @arkascha how to use it in php ??

Comment: Why would one want to setup a database in php? But anyway, you can obviously use any command line argument via the `exec()`, `system()` or similar functions.

Comment: @arkascha i write this exec(mysqldump -d -u root -p stock > mydatabase.sql); it give me this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'root' (T_STRING)

Comment: `exec()` expects a string as an argument. So you have to enclose your command in quotes...

Comment: @arkascha exec('mysqldump -d -u root -p stock > mydatabase.sql'); i put it like this put it didn't give me a file with th database

Comment: So what error does your http servers error log file show?

Comment: @arkascha no error put don't have a file

Comment: Oh, that obviously cannot work. You are trying to use the interactive `-p` flag in a non-interactive environment. How do you want to enter the password? Easiest is to add a `backup` user or similar with read access that does _not_ require a password. But as said before: _why_? Why not simply do that on the command line directly instead of the php way?

Comment: You certainly _do_ have an error log file your http server writes. Unless you explicitly deactivated it, that is. Maybe you don't know about the log files?

Comment: @arkascha i don't know what you mean exactly if you can give me an example for that i want only a file with my tables db empty

Comment: @arkascha i get a file but it is empty

Comment: So what is your current command for that? Did you create a backup user so that you can use the command without a password prompt? You can limit access for that user to the local system for security reasons. What happens if you run that command directly in a shell (I think MS-Windows calls its minimal shell "Command line prompt" or something, sorry, I am not familiar with these systems)? You should have something like `mysqldump --no-data -u backup stock > stock.structure.sql`.

Comment: @arkascha i use your commad like this and it give me an empty file without any thing on it <?php system("mysqldump --no-data -u backup stock > stock.structure.sql");?>

Comment: You _did_ create that user inside MySQL with "dump" and "select" access permissions to the "stock" database? As said before: you need to take a look into your http servers error log file. That is where you can _read_ what the issue is. You cannot program php without monitoring that file. Take a look into your http servers configuration files to find out where the log files are located on your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

1) go to your browser and visit localhost/phpmyadmin

2) select your database which you wish to copy without data

3) go to export tag without entering in any table of database

4) Select export method : custom option

5) keep default format as SQL as same but change in Format-specific options:

> structure and data

option to

> **structure**

only ( this will help to not copy any data of tables)

6) then click on Go and you will get your expored file

7) create any new empty database with anyother name and import upper sql file in that.

*You will get the copy of your database without any data.*

Answer (score 0):

Simple..

- Export your DB
- Truncate your DB
- Now export it again so that it will become empty copy of this database with the tables
- When you are done import the data by the file you have exported in step 1

;)

Comment: how do i truncate my db?

Comment: MySQL oers a `truncate` command. A single google search would have shown that.